# Drupal 7: How to create dynamic link based upon url

Tags: routes

I simply want a menu item which scans the url, grabs the second argument, and plugs it into the second wildcard location of the new menu item it's creating.

So if the URL is: http://drupal.org/contenttype1/johndoe (johndoe = 2nd argument)

the menu item displayed will be: http://drupal.org/contenttype2/johndoe (johndoe = wildcard location)

So far, based upon a [few forum](http://drupal.org/node/646468), I've sketched out the following code, which is clearly incomplete, and it is doing nothing right now.

Basically, I just want this menu item to link to an existing page mysite.com/[coach name]/page. I'm using clean URLs by the way.

```
        <?php
    function coachmenu_menu() {
      $items = array();

      $items['%/page'] = array(
        'title' => 'Coach Page',
        'page callback' => 'coachpagelink',
        'page arguments' => array('0'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'menu_name'=>"menu-coach-menu",
      );
        return $items;
    }

    function coachpagelink($wildcard) {
        return $wildcard;
    }
```

Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine except for a detail. The correct menu definition is the following one.

```
$items['%/page'] = array(
  'title' => 'Coach Page',
  'page callback' => 'coachpagelink',
  'page arguments' => array(0),  // Use an integer, not a string.
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'menu_name'=>"menu-coach-menu",
);
```

If you use a string in the page arguments, the page callback is not receiving part of the URL, but that string. In your case, the page callback is always receiving `'0'` as argument, even when the page callback is invoked for example.com/jhondoe/page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, wildcards cannot be used as a first argument. See "Simple Wildcards" under "Wildcards in Paths" section in [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) documentation.